# How to loop through crispy fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

How can I arrange my form in a table?

I had a normal form and I was arranging it in my template like this.

```
<table border="0" >
    {% for field in form %}
        <tr >
            <td>
                <label for="{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label_tag }}
                    {% if field.field.required %}<span style="color:red"; class="special_class">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now I want to use crispy forms. but couldn't figure out how to display my form.

of cause it has works with this.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
```

but that was not arranging my fields well,

how can I access these fields by a loop? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s wrong with the arrangement? Looks like your page fails to load the relevant css file

Comment: I want to use a table with this form elements, which I did with normal form. but it does not load its field with the way I did (using {% for field in form %}). And I do not have a css file but base css is loading properly

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate over fields and then use crispy like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
{% endfor %}
```